# Plotting contours on a global map using ggplot and orthographic projection

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour, orthographic, r-sf

I am trying to plot a map like this one using ggplot and this [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/57qeekwm920lxbu/dataset.txt?dl=0) :

[image]

Using this code:

```
dev.off()
map.world <- map_data("world")
plot <- ggplot()
plot <- ggplot(data=DATASET, aes(V2,V1,fill=V3)) + 
stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..,alpha=..level..),
geom='polygon',colour='black') + 
scale_fill_continuous(low="green",high="red") +guides(alpha="none") 
plot <- plot + expand_limits(x = map.world$long, y = map.world$lat)
plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), 
panel.border=element_blank())
plot <- plot + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.text=element_blank())
plot <- plot + theme(legend.position="right",plot.title = element_text(size = 
10, face = "bold"))
plot <- plot + coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(90, -90, 0)) 
plot
```

I get this map:

[image]

As you see, in some locations, the contours are distorted. However, when I add the country maps:

```
dev.off()
map.world <- map_data("world")
plot <- ggplot()
plot <- ggplot(data=DATASET, aes(V2,V1,fill=V3)) + 
stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..,alpha=..level..),geom='polygon',
colour='black') + 
scale_fill_continuous(low="green",high="red") +guides(alpha="none")    
plot <- plot + geom_map(dat=map.world, map = map.world, aes(map_id=region), 
fill="NA", color="black")
plot <- plot + expand_limits(x = map.world$long, y = map.world$lat)
plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), 
panel.border=element_blank())
plot <- plot + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.text=element_blank())
plot <- plot + theme(legend.position="right",plot.title = element_text(size = 
10, face = "bold"))
plot <- plot + coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(90, -90, 0)) 
plot
```

I get this message:

> `"Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'V2' not found"`.

I would appreciate your help.

You can download the dataset [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/57qeekwm920lxbu/dataset.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, but the issue with `object 'V2' not found` is because when you first build the ggplot object, you map V2, V1, and V3 as aesthetics. These will carry through to all the layers, unless you override them or specify that a layer shouldn't inherit them. Adding `inherit.aes = F` to your `geom_map` fixes it.

```r
library(tidyverse)

DATASET <- read.delim("https://www.dropbox.com/s/57qeekwm920lxbu/dataset.txt?dl=1", header = F)

map.world <- map_data("world")
plot <- ggplot()
plot <- ggplot(data=DATASET, aes(V2,V1,fill=V3)) + 
    stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..,alpha=..level..),geom='polygon',
                                 colour='black') + 
    scale_fill_continuous(low="green",high="red") +guides(alpha="none")    
plot <- plot + geom_map(dat=map.world, map = map.world, aes(map_id=region), 
                                                fill="NA", color="black", inherit.aes = F)
# plot <- plot + expand_limits(x = map.world$long, y = map.world$lat)
plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), 
                                         panel.border=element_blank())
# plot <- plot + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.text=element_blank())
plot <- plot + theme(legend.position="right",plot.title = element_text(size = 
                                                                                                                                                10, face = "bold"))
plot <- plot + coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(90, -90, 0)) 
print(plot)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

I turned the tick marks back on, just to try to figure out the limits issue, which I believe is what's making the stray lines. Some points are outside the coordinate limits, but I'm not sure how to fix that exactly. Maybe someone else has a suggestion on how to tweak `expand_limits` or `lims`---so far, I'm not getting quite there.

I did find this in the manual page for `coord_map`:

```r
# Centered on New York (currently has issues with closing polygons)
worldmap + coord_map("ortho", orientation = c(41, -74, 0))
```

So this might be a known issue.